# Show that $A^{(x,y)}$ is countable.

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-verification

Question: Let $A$ be a countable set $A^{(x,y)}$ the set of all functions from $(x,y)$ to $A$. Show that $A^{(x,y)}$ is countable.

My attempt:

By proposition 7.1.2iii, $\mid B \mid^{\mid A \mid}$ is the cardinality of the set of functions from $A$ into $B$ . Also, by definition 6.6.1, A function $f$ from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ is a subset of $ X \times Y$ with the following property:

$(\forall x \in x)( \exists! y \in Y)[(x,y) \in f]$

The set $X$ is the domain of $f$ and the set $Y$ is the codomain of $F$. For each $x \in X$ the unique calue $y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$ is denoted by $f(x) $ and is called the image of $x$.

Suppose that $x = f(x)$ and $y=f(y)$. Then each function $(x,y) \rightarrow A$ is a subset $[([f(x)_1,f(y)_1],a_1,[f(x)_2,f(y)_2],a_2...[f(x)_m,f(y)_m],a_m$ where each element $a_i=f(x_i),f(y_i)$. The function $f$ is uniquely determined by the list $a_1,a_2,...a_m$.

Conversely, there is a one to one correspondence to $ A \times A$. We can count the required set of functions by counting the sets of lists $a_1,a_2,...a_m$. As there are exactly $A$ options for each $a_i$, the cardinality of the set of these lists is $ \mid A \mid \cdot \mid A \mid.... \mid A \mid$ (m factors)

giving $A^m = A^{(x,y)}$

Is this correct? If not, then how do I improve on this proof?

Edit:

Second attempt. For $ \mid A \mid ^x]$

Suppose that $ x =[x_1,x_2,...x_m]$. Each function $f: X \rightarrow A$ is a subset of $ X \times A$ of the form $(x_1,a_1)(x_2,a_2),...,(x_m,a_m)$ where each element $a_i=f(x_i)$. The function $f$ is uniquely determined by the list $a_1,a_2,...a_m$. Conversely, each such list determines a unique function from $X$ to $A$ . This bijection (between lists and functions) implies that we can count the required set of lists $a_1,a_2,...a_m$ as there are exactly $ \mid A \mid$ options for each term $a_1$ the cardinality of the set of these lists is  $ \mid A \mid \cdot \mid A \mid.... \mid A \mid$ (m factors)

giving $A^m = A^{x}$

Similarly, for $\mid A \mid ^y$

Suppose that $ y =[y_1,y_2,...y_m]$. Each function $f: Y \rightarrow A$ is a subset of $ Y \times A$ of the form $(y_1,a_1)(y_2,a_2),...,(y_m,a_m)$ where each element $a_i=f(y_i)$. The function $f$ is uniquely determined by the list $a_1,a_2,...a_m$. Conversely, each such list determines a unique function from $Y$ to $A$ . This bijection (between lists and functions) implies that we can count the required set of lists $a_1,a_2,...a_m$ as there are exactly $ \mid A \mid$ options for each term $a_1$ the cardinality of the set of these lists is  $ \mid A \mid \cdot \mid A \mid.... \mid A \mid$ (m factors)

giving $A^m = A^{y}$

Comment: You need to clarify your notation.  It is unclear what $(x,y)$ is.  In particular, if $(x,y)$ are "already chosen" (i.e., not implicitly quantified), then there are exactly $|A|$ functions $f_a\colon (x,y)\mapsto a$.

Comment: @nomen there are supposed to be brackets for x,y, but latex keeps eating it up.... $\{x,y\}$ to A.

Answer (score 1):

I got a little confused reading some of the later stuff in your proof... but I did get that you say for functions from $A$ to $B$ the cardinality is $$|B|^{|A|}$$ So in this case the cardinality is $$|A|^2$$ since there are two elements in $(x,y)$. You just have to show that the product of two countable sets is countable.

EDIT: Ok let's start a new area since this is getting messy.
We have: $A$ is a countable set.
What are $x,y$ and $(x,y)$. What is $m$ and what is $A^m$? I'm getting confused because I'm not clear on what everything represents here.

EDIT2: I think I understand the hint. So you want to list of all possible functions from the SET $$\{x,y\}$$ to the countable set $A$. For each function, you need to make exactly 2 choices: where does $x$ get sent, and where does $y$ get sent? That means that picking a function is *equivalent* to picking a pair of elements from the set $A$. So the set of functions is in correspondence with the set of pairs of elements from $A$, which is just the set $$A\times A$$

EDIT3: Let's make it concrete. Let $$A=\{1,2,3\}$$ Then the possible functions are:

1. $f(x)=1,f(y)=1$
2. $f(x)=1,f(y)=2$
3. $f(x)=1,f(y)=3$
4. $f(x)=2,f(y)=1$

.
.
.

1. $f(x)=3,f(y)=3$

Each function is like a possible pair from $A\times A$:

1. 1,1
2. 1,2
3. 1,3
4. 2,1

. 
.
.

1. 3,3

Comment: so I have to show $\mid A \mid$ $ \mid A \mid$ ?

Comment: That's a quantity, not a truth claim... but yes, something like that...

Comment: oh wait what if I split the original problem up so it becomes $ \mid A \mid ^ x$ and $\mid A \mid ^y$? and then apply the definition again. Would that work ? Or do I apply the definition to $\mid A \mid \mid A \mid$? which is $A^2$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are two elements of a set right?

Comment: yes...they are... the book only showed the definition and the proof for it which had only one element of A.

Comment: So you could take $|A|^{|x|}$ and $|A|^{|y|}$ - note that $|\{x\}|=1$ because the set has one element. And then multiply the two... have you seen the proof that the rationals are countable? That same proof (the "diagonal" argument) demonstrates that any product of two countable sets is countable (and can you improve it?!)

Comment: ok I understand the $|A|^{|x|}$ and $|A|^{|y|}$ part... I could apply the definition and the proposition... but what I don't get is the the multiply the two part.

Comment: I've edited my entry and added a second attempt. @user142299

Comment: I think you mean $|A^x|=|A|^{m}$... but yes, it looks like you are on the right track. Pay attention to the difference between a set $S$ and its order $|S|$. One is a set the other a number.

Comment: really? THe book had something like this $B^m = B^{a}$ on the example... so how do I multiply $ \mid A \mid ^{x}$ and  $\mid A \mid ^y$ together to have $ \mid A \mid ^ {x,y}$ @user142299

Comment: see edit that I added to the post  @usukidoll

Comment: the question was let $A$ be a countable set and $A^{x,y}$ the set of all functions from $(x,y)$ to $A$. SHow that $A^{x,y}$ is countable

Comment: What are x and y? Are they elements? Is (x,y) a set? If so, please write as $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: yes it's the set of all functions from $\{x,y\}$ to $A$

Comment: Ok. Then what is the variable $m$?

Comment: well while I was reading the example for $ \mid B \mid ^{a}$ the m factors were $ \mid B \mid .\mid B \mid ......\mid B \mid$

Comment: I was given a hint about this problem. 

We have a 1-1 correspondence to $ A \times A$....$A \times A 3 (a,b) = [(f(x),f(y)]$  which is the graph of a function from  $\{x,y\}$ to $A$. The $(f(x),f(y))$ are functions... IF $A$ is countable, so is $A \times A$

Comment: What is $a$ and where did $|B|$ come from?! All these variables!! I'll add another edit see that.

Comment: By proposition 7.1.2iii, $\mid B \mid^{\mid A \mid}$ is the cardinalityof the set of functions from $A$ into $B$ .

Comment: ouch now I'm confused after I gave the hint out D:, but I did split the problem up which is what I wrote in the second attempt, but how do I put this together? or is it just one huge mess?

Comment: Several huge messes :) So did you get what I wrote? For each function f you need to pick what f(x) will be and what f(y) will be. So you need to choose a pair (a1,a2) of elements from the set A. In other words, the set of all functions is just like the set of all pairs from A: A$\times$A.

Comment: so are the set of all pairs from $A : A \times A$ related to $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ ?

Comment: Right. Each function is like one of those pairs, and all the functions together is like the whole set $A\times A$.

Comment: greattttt........ what if $f(x) $ is $1$, $f(y)$ is $1$ and all pairs from $A : A \times A$ is $1$ would that work since all of them have the same value?

Comment: See third edit. As to the question, f(x) can equal f(y), sure. What do you mean by "all pairs are 1"? The pairs are each two values like (1,1) or (apple,pear)...

Comment: yes I am seeing it a lot clearer, but should I include the proof for the $A^x$ and the $A^y$ along with that example?

Comment: I think your proofs were getting at the same idea that my last edit was. In general, if you have $m$ elements in a set $\{x_1,...,x_m\}$, then the functions from X to A are all of the form $\{(x_1,a_1),...,(x_m,a_m)\}$ so there are $$|A|^m$$ possible functions. That is the order of the set of possible functions.

Comment: In this case $m=2$ because the set is $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: oh I see it now ^^. Took a long while. kind of new at this XD

Comment: Note also that $A^2=A\times A$.

Comment: DOH! Now I am really seeing it ... that's like prop . 7.1.2.ii $ \mid A \mid . \mid B \mid = \mid A \times B \mid $

Only since we are dealing with 2 A's

$\mid A \mid . \mid A \mid = \mid A \times A \mid$

Comment: @usukidoll So it makes sense?!

Comment: yes it does....I'm starting to see it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use your proposition 7.1.2iii (but note that it is wrong as stated.  There are $|A|^{|B|}$ function from $B$ **to** $A$, not $B$ **into** $A$):

$$|A^{\{x,y\}}| = |A|^{|\{x,y\}|} = |A|^2$$.

At this point, you want to use an enumeration argument.  Construct a "table" of values in $A\times A$ and traverse it, just like you would for the rationals.

Comment: It's wrong? But I've typed it exactly as the text.

Comment: @nomen What's the difference between "to" and "in to"?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong.  In general, there are fewer injections of $B$ **into** $A$ than functions from $B$ **to** $A$.

Comment: @user142299: it's a bit of usage.  When you say "$f$ is a function of $A$ into $B$", you're saying that $f$ is an injection (one-to-one) -- that is, if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $a = b$.

Comment: @nomen Ok I've never heard that before - probably their book doesn't use that convention. (I have heard "onto" but never "into").

Comment: yeah I've heard about onto as well... which is surjection... don't recall an into term at all

Comment: Right, if $f$ is a function from $A$ **onto** $B$, then it is a surjection.  If $f$ is a function from $A$ **into** $B$, then it is an injection.  It's kind of nice -- if $f$ is "onto", it "covers" all of the elements of the codomain.  If $f$ is into, the domain is "covered" by all the elements of the codomain.  Note that I am using "cover" in a suggestive way, not a technical way.

Comment: But if the book isn't using the convention, feel free to ignore the point, and keep an eye out for it in other books.  If you're not sure which convention is being used, figure it out. :)